# Porting scipy.ndimage.filters correlate1d from Python to C++ or C#

Tags: c#, c++, python, scipy

I need to port some code from python (a prototype which i haven't written), into C# and C++.
The original python code makes use of [scipy.ndimage.filters correlate1d](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.correlate1d.html) with the mode = "wrap". As far as I understood, wrap is a manner of normalizing the output of the correlation.

Do you know of any C++ (or C#/.Net) available function/library that would perform such an algorithm (it should provides a really similar output), or do you know of what the algorithm in wrap mode corresponds to ? I could code the algorithm as a solution, but I have no idea what is the formula behind the wrap mode.

Comment: For whatever it's worth, `mode='wrap'` controls the way that boundary conditions are handled, not the way that the output is normalized.

Comment: A short explanation of what `mode='wrap'` boundary conditions are is here: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/ndimage.html#filter-functions  Basically, if you're extending `[1, 2, 3]` by 1 in either direction it would yield `[3, 1, 2, 3, 1]`. If you want to dig into the details, the relevant code (in C) is here: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/ndimage/src/ni_support.c#L198

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@JoeKington had commented the question giving the link to github branch of scipy, with [the C code for the function correlate1d](http://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/ndimage/filters.py)..